# asyncio - creating a task but never using await

Tags: python-asyncio

I wanted to know what happens when i call `asyncio.create_task` and never actually calling await on this created task.

i have this simple program:

```
import asyncio

async def simple_task() -> None:
    while True:
        print("before sleeping")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("after sleeping")

async def test():
    task = asyncio.create_task(simple_task())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(test())
```

I'm creating a task, which should run forever, and im never using await.
When running this, the output i get is:

```
before sleeping

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my question is:

- why did the task actually run when i never called await?
- if it did start running, why did it stop after the sleep?

Answer (score 0):

This code is written to say “run until `test` completes”. `test` creates a task to run `simple_task` and then ends. The event loop gives anything already scheduled against it one last chance to run before stopping.

At this point `simple_task` gets to start executing. It prints, and then yields control back to the loop via `asyncio.sleep`.

Nothing else was scheduled against the loop so it stops. `asyncio.run` then closes the loop.

If you schedule more things against the event loop you may see more iterations of `simple_task`, but there’s really no way to have asyncio run something forever without waiting for it to do so (`loop.run_forever` is probably the closest you’ll get).